# How to change jqGrid caption background color?

Tags: jqgrid

I have multiple jqGrids displayed on a page and I would like to display different caption background color for each one.  How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.  This seems to work

```
$("#mygrid").closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").children("div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar").children("span.ui-jqgrid-title").css("background-color", "goldenrod");
```